# how to fill NAs between two known values in a dataframe column with a linear equation?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, lapply

I have several dfs stored in lists that have a 0 value in the first row and the first non-zero value around the 6th row or more. I would like to be able to fill the missing values between 0 and my first value with a simple linear equation. I don't care if the the linear equation doesnt fit well with the other values past the first non-zero one, I just need to connect the first row (0) to the first non-zero value for each column.

| Year | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 | Var4 | Var4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NA |
| 1 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 2 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 3 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 4 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 5 | 2.03 | 14.567 | NA | 14.67 | NA |
| 6 | 3.467 | 17.87 | 3.32 | 19.54 | NA |
| 7 | 7.11 | 24.83 | 5.65 | 30.91 | 13.46 |

My first thought was to do it manually and repeat those 4 lines for all my list elements but because some columns have their first value after the 6th row, I would need to adjust and repeat the same operation over and over for each exception. I don't want to erase any existing data so I can't select the furthest value and apply this method for the whole datafame.

```
list1$`df1`[2,-1] <- (list1$`df1`[6,-1]/5)*1
list1$`df1`[3,-1] <- (list1$`df1`[6,-1]/5)*2
list1$`df1`[4,-1] <- (list1$`df1`[6,-1]/5)*3
list1$`df1`[5,-1] <- (list1$`df1`[6,-1]/5)*4
```

I tried with a sapply() inside a lapply() to target the first value other than 0 as well as the corresponding row, but I'm very far from applying a calculation to it in order to fill the previous rows. Otherwise, I also tried with functions of type '*fill()*' but all it does is copy the same value.

`firstval <- lapply(list1, function(x) sapply(x[,-1], function(y) y[min(which(!is.na(y) & y>0))]`

`rownum <- lapply(list1, function(x) sapply(x[,-1], function(y) min(which(!is.na(y) & y>0))))`

The final result should look like this with all the NAs filled with a linear equation between 0 (first row) and the first non-zero value.

| Year | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 | Var4 | Var5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | **0** | **0** | **0** | **0** | **0** |
| 1 | *0.41* | *2.91* | *0.55* | *2.93* | *1.92* |
| 2 | *0.81* | *5.82* | *1.11* | *5.87* | *3.85* |
| 3 | *1.22* | *8.74* | *1.66* | *8.80* | *5.77* |
| 4 | *1.62* | *11.65* | *2.21* | *11.74* | *7.69* |
| 5 | **2.03** | **14.56** | *2.77* | **14.67** | *9.61* |
| 6 | **3.47** | **17.87** | **3.32** | **19.54** | *11.54* |
| 7 | **7.11** | **24.83** | **5.65** | **30.91** | **13.46** |

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What you are doing is usually called "linear interpolation"; if you search using those terms you'll find lots of stuff, probably leading you to functions like `zoo::na.approx` or `forecast::na.interp` each of which can probably be applied to columns using `mutate()` and `across()` all in one go.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the reproducible input, `L`, shown in the Note at the end -- next time please provide a reproducible example.

Apply `na.approx` to each data frame as shown.

```
library(zoo)
lapply(L, function(x) as.data.frame(na.approx(x, na.rm = FALSE)))
```

### Note

```
DF <- structure(list(Year = 0:7, Var1 = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.03, 
3.467, 7.11), Var2 = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14.567, 17.87, 24.83
), Var3 = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.32, 5.65), Var4 = c(0, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 14.67, 19.54, 30.91), Var4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 13.46)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
L <- list(DF, DF, DF)
```